# ActiveAdmin, navigation_menu with custom order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using Runy On Rails with ActiveAdmin gem. In my admin configuration I have an AdminPage (`Clients`) which shouldn't be in the usual menu. It should be in the navigatio menu of one related AdminPage (`Company`). In this way, I can see the clients of the company.

So, in my `app/admin/people.rb` I have:

`navigation_menu :company`

Inside this menu, I have other elements too, and everything work like a charm. Now, I want to apply custom order over these items. But when I use `priority` (as I use in the usual menu items in the application) my model lose its `navigation_menu`.

So, I can't have a sub-menu with custom priority.

Can I modify the priority/order on a `navigation_menu`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this indeed is an ActiveAdmin issue.

I managed to workaround using the monkey patch described below of [add_to_menu](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource/menu.rb#L52) method.

It's not the most elegant, but it does the job while the issue gets fixed in AA.

Imagine you want 2 parent menu items `Clients` and `Product`, and each one of these has 2 children.  All these admin pages scoped within `navigation_menu :company`, for example:

```
Clients
-> 1. ClientAddresses
-> 2. ClientProfiles

Products
-> 1. ProductCategories
-> 2. ProductCosts
```

So the monkey patch goes like:

```
# Put this in app/admin/components/menu.rb
module ActiveAdmin
  class Resource
    module Menu
      def add_to_menu(menu_collection)
        add_parent_options if forced_parents.keys.include? resource_name.plural.to_sym
        if include_in_menu?
          @menu_item = menu_collection.add navigation_menu_name, menu_item_options
        end
      end

      def add_parent_options
        priority, parent = forced_parents[resource_name.plural.to_sym]
        @menu_item_options[:priority] = priority
        @menu_item_options[:parent] = I18n.t("active_admin.menus.#{parent}")
      end

      def forced_parents
        @forced_parents ||=
          {
            client_addresses: [1, :clients],
            client_profiles: [2, :clients],
            product_categories: [1, :products],
            product_costs: [2, :products],
          }
      end
    end
  end
```

Good luck